# How do I mask a feed forward layer based on tensor in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a really simple network with 2 inputs (x and m).
x is size 100
m is size 3

My network is simply...

```
f_1 = linear_layer(x)

f_2 = linear_layer(f_1)
f_3 = linear_layer(f_1)
f_4 = linear_layer(f_1)

f_5 = softmax(linear_layer(sum(f_2, f_3, f_4)))
```

based on the vector m, I want to zero out and ignore f_2, f_3, f_4 in the final sum and resulting gradient calculation. Is there a way to create a mask based on vector m to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how you do it. Use list comprehensions to make it more generic:

```
# example input and output
x = torch.ones(5)
y = torch.zeros(3)

# mask tensor
mask = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0])

# initial layer
z0 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)

# layers to potentially mask
z1 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 3)
z2 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 3)
z3 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 3)

# defines how the data passes through the layers, specific mask element is applied to each of the maskable layers
layer1_output = z0(x)
layer2_output = mask[0]*z1(layer1_output) + mask[1]*z2(layer1_output) + mask[2]*z3(layer1_output)

# loss function
loss = torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(layer2_output, y)

# run it and see
loss.backward()
print(z0.weight.grad)
print(z1.weight.grad)
print(z2.weight.grad)
print(z3.weight.grad)
```

as shown below, the masking tensor is effective in selecting subnets to apply computation to  based on mask element

```
tensor([[ 0.0354,  0.0354,  0.0354,  0.0354,  0.0354],
        [-0.0986, -0.0986, -0.0986, -0.0986, -0.0986],
        [-0.0372, -0.0372, -0.0372, -0.0372, -0.0372],
        [-0.0168, -0.0168, -0.0168, -0.0168, -0.0168],
        [-0.0133, -0.0133, -0.0133, -0.0133, -0.0133]])
tensor([[-0., 0., 0., -0., 0.],
        [-0., 0., 0., -0., 0.],
        [-0., 0., 0., -0., 0.]])
tensor([[-0.0422,  0.1314,  0.1108, -0.1644,  0.0906],
        [-0.0240,  0.0747,  0.0630, -0.0934,  0.0515],
        [-0.0251,  0.0781,  0.0659, -0.0977,  0.0539]])
tensor([[-0., 0., 0., -0., 0.],
        [-0., 0., 0., -0., 0.],
        [-0., 0., 0., -0., 0.]])
```